# Symfony: how to pass a parameter from Route to Controller with no path

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I have a route

```
   detail:
      path:     /{code}
      defaults: { _controller: controller.main:detailAction }
```

I also have a controller for this route

```
 public function detailAction(Request $request, string $code, int $size, array $params): Response
 {
 }
```

My question is: how can I say to controller which parameters he should take as `int $size` and `array $params` ? I have found in symfony docs that I may specifically mention params in `defaults` section with default values like this

```
   detail:
      path:     /{code}
      defaults: { _controller: controller.main:detailAction }
      size:        1
      params:      "Hello world!"
```

But that is not what I want since I shouldn't have a default value for this params but it ought to be taken directly from request. How do I do this without making my route like `/{code}/{size}` ? 
And even in this case what do I do with an array?

Comment: Are you saying sometimes there's just a code, sometimes a code + size, and sometimes a code + size + params?

Comment: no, as my `detailAction()` statement requires all arguments, it always must be all parameters passed. But only `$code` is part of the path, others I just want to have passed

Comment: I would make the arguments optional: `detailAction(..., int $size = null, array $params = null)`. Then you can test if they're set, but I don't believe (?) Symfony's router will see those as required arguments.

Comment: So like: https://3v4l.org/iOLga

Comment: This question makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a url like this by passing parameters in your controller:

```
 $url = $this->generateUrl("detail", array("code" => $code, ...));

    return $this->redirect($url);
```

And routing:

```
  detail:
     path:     /
     defaults: { _controller: controller.main:detailAction }
```

Comment: In symfony >= 3.3 you can directly do `return $this->redirectToRoute('detail', array('code' => $code....));`

Comment: is it the only way? Can't I state in my routing that some parameters should be clearly passed (size -> $size etc)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify parameters like this

```
someurl.io/action/?filter=allopenissues&orderby=created
```

You should typehint Request object in your action and access its query parameters bag. If your controller extends Symfony Controllers, Request will be automatically passed.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
....
public function updateAction(Request $request)
{
    $request->query->get('myParam'); // get myParam from query string 
}
```